# how to send html email using Mac Outlook

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook

I've designed an HTML email in Adobe Dreamweaver.

How do I send this as an email in Outlook for Mac (v16.31)?

Comment: 1. https://youtu.be/4FIC52eSXYs                                                                                                    2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XHx5YtR1r0

Comment: They're both for Outlook on Windows, @Pie.

Comment: Watch this first video from 0:53, it is for Outlook for Mac

Comment: The first video @ 0:53 talks about Mac Mail, not Outlook for Mac @Aidan.

Comment: Outlook for Windows and Outlook for Mac tend to have the same options. Are you able to clarify which specific step you are struggling with? I should also point out that email clients do not use a modern version of HTML, you should check the compatibility with a service like [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) first or your email might not work as you expect.